# How to represent inverse of a multivariable function?

Tags: functions, notation

Consider a function $f(x,y) = x^2 + x*y + y^2$.
What is the correct notation to mean "find the value of $x$ that will make $f(x, y = 3)$ equal to $1$"? Something like $f^{-1}(1,3)$, which clearly is not working.

Comment: You are trying to find the set $\{x \, | \, f(x,3)=1\}$.

Comment: also, with real numbers, the set is empty, as $x^2 +xy + y^2 \geq 3 y^2 /4$

Comment: @AnuragA I was hoping for a more concise notation so that I could use it in a sentence like "The value of x can be determined using $f^{-1}(1,3)$." 
I guess, will just say "The value of x can be determined by solving $f(x,3)=1$"

Comment: I would write $\left. {f^{\, - 1} (1)} \right|_{y = 3} $, of course with some words of explanation